# How to port Android kitkat on Panda board?

Tags: android, porting, omap, pandaboard, bsp

I want to learn Android BSP porting.For that I want to port Android kitkat on TI's Panda board.I have already done the Linux porting on panda board.Please suggest the starting point for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried similar thing on Exynos5250 development board with partial success. With partial I mean, the system is up, shell is accessible, all partitions are mounted. But display is not up. So I may guide you a little bit. I may describe what I did for this.

First of all take two source codes.
    1) AOSP to which you want to port your Pandaboard. 
    2) Take any working Andoroid source, it may be ICS or JB or even KK.

Now, You need to port your **HARDWARE BOARD** to **KITKAT SOURCE(1)**

So, get KK aosp and build it once for any device already available in source. Follow,

- https://source.android.com/source/building.html

Now follow this link in XDA forum.

- http://forum.xda-developers.com/chef-central/android/guide-android-rom-development-t2814763

This describes things if you are starting from scratch.

Or if your machine is already set for building AOSP with proper tools refer specifically

- http://forum.xda-developers.com/chef-central/android/guide-android-rom-development-t2814763#9

This shows what to change and where to change. Just note that you may not have cm.mk file as that is specifically for cyanogenmod.

There are few useful links in my bookmark bar that you may refer when the code is building(It takes hours, believe me)

- http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_porting_intro
- http://elinux.org/Android_Device
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2620389
- http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html
- [Android device configuration for AOSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352709/android-device-configuration-for-aosp)

You may use the JB kernel for a while to boot it up as I did, but it will break some features in Kitkat android.

Also, I while building you may face a lot of errors. You need to deal with them on your own.

Also if you successfully port it, don't forget to share the process you followed.

I hope this will provide a good start for the process. Good Luck.

Comment: Sunil : Thanks for great help.I am able to port android kitkat on Pandabaord. After everything I am able to access adb shell but I am stuck at the same problem that you were facing ,Screen is not coming up after connecting Monitor to panda-board using HDMI.

Comment: this is a known issue and you need propriety libraries from imgtec for this.(imgtec-panda-20130603-539d1ac3.tgz).Just google imgtec-panda-20130603-539d1ac3.tgz and first link will take you to doenload this script which you have to extract and run in the Android Source directory.Build the android and you will have the Android Display Live via HDMI.Voila !!!