# How to build a device tree?

Tags: android, build, device-tree

Ok, I wanted to build custom ROM for my device (let's say i want lineage os ex cyanogenmod), but there isn't device tree anywhere. So how to build device tree I couldn't find any tutorial for that out there. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352709/android-device-configuration-for-aosp) I learned a little. But how to find out what folders (I saw folders named bluetooth gps and such) do I need and what files has to be in them? I guess it's different for each device but how to fin what I need for mine?

Device is LG K350nds