# procedure to add custom device in AOSP device folder

Tags: android, android-source, android-firmware

I know this question has been asked before but I wanted customize according to my problem so,
1. I am new to adding this custom board to AOSP target devices.
2. I have the kernel and necessary modules compiled now please guide me to link it with my device folder in AOSP devices list.
3. I know the basic .mk files to be created in device folder and I have created, but not sure if it is rightly done.
Android.mk,AndroidProducts.mk,BoardConfig.mk,myproduct.mk,vendorsetup.sh.

Comment: Your question is unclear and far too broad. " I have created, but not sure if it is rightly done" then please add these files to your question or how should we know if you implemented them correct?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand `build layers` and the `device tree`. Here are the references for you,

[Adding a new device](https://source.android.com/source/add-device.html)

> but not sure if it is rightly done.
>   Android.mk,AndroidProducts.mk,BoardConfig.mk,myproduct.mk,vendorsetup.sh

Below link has good explanations on device configuration files,

[Android device configuration for AOSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352709/android-device-configuration-for-aosphttp://)